# Restore file from git repo without commit

Tags: git, github, version-control

I deleted a file from my local workspace and then realized I needed it. I have not commited or pushed to the repo yet, so I would like to get that file back to my local workspace.

My issue is my local repo is 10 commits ahead of the remote master, therefore simply cloning the master is not good, nor is checking out a different commit. I'm afraid I'll either wipe my local repo and source, or screw things up more.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't committed that change yet, the following will give you the file back:

```
git checkout <filename>
```

The exact filename can be obtained via `git status`.

Comment: well I seem to continue to find things in git are simpler than they appear! - Thanks, this did the trick quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you did commit your changes and want to get a file from an earlier revision, you can get it using the command

```
git show <revision>:<filename> > <new-filename>
```

(without redirecting output it will simply display the file revision's contents in `less`).

Answer (score 2):

If you did a `git add file`, its contents *at that moment* is saved in the index, and you can get it back by `git checkout file`. If you didn't `add` it, but it had been `commit`ed before, you'll get back the last version.